# I accidently disabled registry tools

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, regedit

I was wondering if there was a way to restore registry editor editor acess after running this in batch command:

```
REG add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /t Reg_dword /v DisableRegistryTools /f /d 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hopefully this serves as a lesson to you in the future that you should avoid playing around in the registry unless you really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Or at least play around in a virtual machine that you don't care about

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commands from the run prompt

```
REG add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" /v DisableCMD /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

REG add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /t Reg_dword /v DisableRegistryTools /f /d 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the run prompt try these two commands:

```
REG add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" /v DisableCMD /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

REG add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /t Reg_dword /v DisableRegistryTools /f /d 0
```